# What hand is this?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, dealing, dealer

I've been starting to learn poker recently (as a reference, I tend to use [this list of hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)). I was watching a tournament and this hand showed up.

One player has a 99, the other a JJ. I understand the JJ wins, but why does the dealer raise the K, Q & 7?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96MhC.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A poker hand is 5 cards, so the dealer is showing that the winning hand is JJKQ7. If, instead, the winning hand had been AhKh for a flush, the dealer instead would have raised the Qh 4h and 7h.